# Entity Framework 4.0 POCO SaveChanges error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I attempt to call SaveChanges() in Entity Framework 4.0 using POCO entities, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=No views were found in assemblies or could be generated for Table 'FnclAttribute'.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace, StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection)
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.<ProduceDynamicCommands>d__0.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCommandOrderer..ctor(IEnumerable`1 commands, UpdateTranslator translator)
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
       at Manatron.AR.Model.Financial.FinancialRepository.PersistFinancialSources(IEnumerable`1 financialSources) in C:\CorpDev\GRM\Dev\AR\AR.Model\Financial\FinancialRepository.cs:line 66
  InnerException:
```

I appear to have the mapping correct for this with regards to the csdl and ssdl in the App.Config file. The code I am using to call this save operation is this:

```
public void PersistFinancialSources( IEnumerable<IFinancialSource> financialSources )
{
  using (FinancialDataContext financialDataContext = _financialDataContextFactory.Create())
  {
    foreach (IFinancialSource financialSource in financialSources)
    {
      var financialSourceEntity = financialSource as FinancialSource;

      if (financialSourceEntity != null)
      {
        IEnumerable<IFinancialAttribute> newFinancialAttributes =
          from financialAmount in financialSource.FinancialAmounts
          where financialAmount.FinancialAttribute.Id < 0
          select financialAmount.FinancialAttribute;

        foreach (FinancialAttribute financialAttribute in newFinancialAttributes)
        {
          financialDataContext.FinancialAttributes.AddObject(financialAttribute);
        }
      }
    }

    financialDataContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.None);
  }
}
```

Any clue what may be the issue? I am having no luck finding info on this error...

Comment: It complains about missing generated view (the mapping transformed into code). Did you pre-generate views from EF?

Comment: Yes, though even when I tried removing the pre-generated views I get the same error

Comment: Have you made any changes to the model after generating those views? These views must be regenerated after every change - it is best to incorporate their generation into build process.

Comment: Nope, the views are up to date. I even see the view for the table in question within my pregenerated views .cs file